# How to interpret the meaning of glGetActiveUniformBlockiv with GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

Suppose I have the following vertex shader code:

```
#version 330
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix, CameraMatrix, SingleModelMatrix;
uniform uint SingleModel;
layout (std140) uniform ModelBlock {
  mat4 ModelMatrices[128];
};

void main(void) {
  ... something that uses ModelMatrices
}
```

If in my program I issue the following OpenGL call for a program object representing the shader above:

```
getUniformBlockParameter(GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE)
```

I find out the following with an Intel HD Graphics 4000 card:

```
GLUniformBlock[
  name: ModelBlock, 
  blockSize: 8192,
  buffer: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192], 
  metadata: {
    ModelMatrices=GLUniformBlockAttributeMetadata[
      name: ModelMatrices, 
      offset: 0, 
      arrayStride: 64,
      matrixStride: 16,
      matrixOrder: 0
  ]},
  uniforms: GLUniformInterface[
    uniforms: {
      ModelMatrices=GLUFloatMat4 [
        name:ModelMatrices, 
        idx:2, 
        loc:-1, 
        size:128, 
        glType:8b5c]
    }
  ]
]
```

How should I interpret the `blockSize` parameter? The [OpenGL 3 sdk docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGetActiveUniformBlock.xml)  state that:

> If pname is `GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE`, the implementation-dependent minimum total buffer object size, **in basic machine units**, required to hold all active uniforms in the uniform block identified by uniformBlockIndex is returned. It is neither guaranteed nor expected that a given implementation will arrange uniform values as tightly packed in a buffer object. The exception to this is the std140 uniform block layout, which guarantees specific packing behavior and does not require the application to query for offsets and strides. In this case the minimum size may still be queried, even though it is determined in advance based only on the uniform block declaration.

So in this case how should I measure that 8192 number in `blockSize`? In `float`s? In `byte`s?

If I do the numbers, a 4x4 matrix `mat4` uniform has a total of 16 `float` components, which fit into 64 `bytes`, so at the very least I need about `16 x 4 x 128` bytes to store 128 matrices which is indeed, `8192`.

Why then is the hardware also asking for 64 (`bytes`?) for array stride and 16 (`bytes`?) of matrix stride, yet requesting only 8192 bytes? Shouldn't `getUniformBlockParameter(GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE)` have requested more space for alignment/padding purposes?

Comment: "*Shouldn't getUniformBlockParameter(GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE) have requested more space for alignment/padding purposes?*" Um, why would it? I don't see a reason here for why the padding and alignment would require allocating more memory?

Comment: Perhaps what I should have said then is, if the card/implementation states that it requires 64 and 16 bytes for array/matrix stride, then I would have expected a full block size bigger than 8192 since obviously, more bytes would be necessary in order to insert the matrix/array strides on the resulting buffer. Does that make more sense? Or maybe I'm still not understanding how the strides work in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array stride is the byte offset from the start of one array element to the start of the next. The array elements in this case are `mat4`s, which are *64 bytes* in size. So the array stride is as small as it can be.

The *matrix* stride is the byte offset from one column/row of matrix data to the next. Each `mat4` has a column or row size of a `vec4`, which means it is *16 bytes* in size. So again, the matrix columns/rows are tightly packed.

So 8KiB is the expected size of such storage.

That being said, this is *entirely* irrelevant. You shouldn't be bothering to query this stuff at all. By using `std140` layout, you have already *forced* OpenGL to adopt a specific layout. One that notably requires `mat4`s to have an array stride of 64 bytes and to have a matrix stride of 16 bytes. You don't have to ask the implementation for this; it's *required* by the standard.

You only need to ask if you're using `shared` or `packed`.

Comment: Ah. I see the point now. What the hardware's telling me is that the stride size/amount is exactly the same as the element's size, hence no padding/alignment is required. What I though was that these strides were required **in addition** to the actual element sizes that use different layouts. I think in that case I would only see strides which are **bigger** than the element sizes. Regardless, since I'm developing a JOGL based port of OGLPlus I would indeed like to support shader code with the other packing types. However, this answer is good enough for the scope of this problem. Thanks again!